# Is this a secure implementation of password reset email?

Tags: protocol-design, authentication

I am redesigning a password reset email mechanism because the existing implementation scares the hell out of me. My goal is to generate reset codes that are:

- Expired
- Tamper Resistant
- Single Use
- Resistant to replay attacks

The format of the reset code I have come up with is:

```
B64( B64( iv ) || B64( E( uid || timestamp ) ) )
```

Where `B64` is base64 encoding and `E` is for symmetric encryption. The `iv` is the initialization vector used for encryption (randomly generated), and is in the clear. The `||` indicates concatenation and I actually use the string `"||"` as the separator. The `uid` is an opaque identifier of the user so I can look them up in the database.

The `timestamp` allows for a code to be expired.

I am using AES 256 in Galois Counter Mode which should provide protection from modified ciphertext attacks.

The encryption key is stored on the server, and used to perform the encryption.

The `iv` has a dual use. When the reset code is generated the `iv` is stored with the user in the database. This is used to enforce single-use of a reset code (it gets cleared when a reset code is processed) as well as prevent use of reset codes generated previously. If the `iv` in the database does not match the `iv` used to decrypt the reset code, the request is refused. This may also help with security in the event that the encryption key on the server is somehow compromised, as the attacker has to inject the `iv` into the database as well to make it work. Of course if the attacker is on the host we are pretty much toast...

Are there any weaknesses in this design I am not seeing, or does it needs additional improvement?

Comment: Why are you only encrypting part of the message?  Why encrypt, and not sign?  Is the randomly generated iv generated using a source of real randomness or cryptographically-strong PRNG?

Comment: Can you store the (uid, timestamp, iv) relation in a db and check that it exists in the database (and is not stale) before allowing reset?

Comment: How are you delivering the reset code to the user? I also think this can be simplified. The reset code could just be a random string, and the timestamp and userID stored on the server with the code.

Comment: This is Java so SecureRandom is being used to generate the IV. Galois Counter Mode includes a MAC so the content can be authenticated. The IV is not encrypted because that is needed for decryption, and I can't look it up without decrypting the associated user first. The IV is matched in the database for the user.

Comment: Using a randomly generated value is much simpler, but I didn't use that for a few reasons. First is that while unlikely, randomly generated values can collide so I would have to not only add an index for lookup but apply a unique constraint as well. Second, while it is an unlikely attack, someone could generate random values and try them against the server and could, however unlikely, hit a user that had generated a reset request that was not yet used and not expired.

Comment: Reading Mike's comment again got me thinking. I think you are asking why am I encrypting the message at all, instead of just signing it. This would mean that the user identifier and timestamp would be passed in the clear, but a keyed MAC would be included for verification. This MAC could then be stored with the user server-side for verification. This would be a simpler implementation. I need to think about the security of this a bit more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe looks secure to me, but excessively complicated.  The following simpler procedure should suffice:

When a password reset token is requested:

- Generate a secure random token and save it (or a cryptographic hash of it) in the database, along with a timestamp.  Overwrite the previous token, if any.
- Send the token to the user by e-mail (suitably encoded).

When the user submits a token:

- Check that it matches the token in the database, and that the corresponding timestamp is not too old.

The only part of the process which needs to involve any cryptography at all is generating the random token, and optionally hashing it.  You can usually offload the former task to the OS; on Unixish systems, for example, you can read the token from `/dev/urandom`.  Alternatively, if you're using a decent crypto library, it should provide a routine for generating secure random numbers (which may call the OS random number generator internally).

---

Ps. The one situation where you might want to go with a more crypto-heavy solution would be if you didn't have access to a convenient database for storing the tokens.  In that case, you could, for example, compute the token as `MACK(userid || timestamp)`, where `MACK` is a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) keyed by the secret key `K`, and have the user submit the timestamp along with the token.  (You could also include a random number in the MAC input, but that's not really necessary — without the key `K`, an attacker won't be able to forge the MAC.)  However, since you *do* have a database available, this doesn't really apply.

Comment: +1 for storing a hash of the token, which means an attacker can't reset passwords by merely getting a DB dump. As an extension, storing H(token,timestamp) and sticking the timestamp in the link works; the main disadvantage I can think of is that you don't know when they can be removed from the DB.

Comment: Yes, after some thought I have to agree. I was going to ditch the encryption and go with using CMAC of userid||timestamp with a randomly generated key, but a random token may suffice. The thing that was bothering me about storing a random token in the database was the possibility of collision and having to store additional indexes and constraints in the database for that token, and a randomly generated attack matching up with a reset request that had not been processed or expired yet. However as you say, I can simply MAC the token before storing it in the database. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @PeterFriend: As long as the token submissions also include the user ID (which they should), you don't have to worry about indexing the tokens or ensuring their uniqueness. And as long as your tokens are long enough (say, 128 bits) brute force attacks will not be practical.

Comment: Treat all password-reset tokens and auto-login tokens as passwords. They essentially *are* passwords. They need to be long and generated by a strong random number generator. When storing them in the database, hash them with a strong adaptive KDF such as bcrypt.

Comment: @Polynomial: The big difference between passwords and authentication tokens is that we get to choose the tokens, and need not take human memorability into account in choosing them. We can easily pick a random 128-bit string as a token, but _very_ few user-chosen passwords will contain that much entropy. In particular, using sufficiently long random tokens obviates the need for key-stretching KDFs (and also allows the use of the same token for both user identification and authentication, although that isn't actually needed in this case).

Comment: That's true -- a simple hash should (probably) do the trick. However, I'd still prefer something like bcrypt, since it protects you from most weaknesses you might discover in the PRNG used to generate the tokens.

Comment: The better token would be `MACk(userid || timestamp || pwdval)`, where `pwdval` is some password-related value that will change once the user resets password (for example, password hash or salt stored in the database). This method ensures that when a user changes the password, the token becomes invalid even if it hasn't expired (i.e. protects against replay attack).

Comment: @Polynomial Using bcrypt would require sending the salt in the clear alongside the source text, wouldn't it? Is that secure?

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman The salt is allowed to be public. It's only there to prevent cross-user precomputation attacks such as rainbow tables.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know good crypto is not easy, and sufficiently good crypto is even harder. So for to start, whatever you do it won't be tamper resistant, tamper resistance means that attacker cannot tamper with some values for his/her own agenda. The property that you are looking for is tamper evidentness, that is the ability to tell whether the supplied message is genuine.

Secondly as you probably noticed, to have a replay protection in such a beautiful protocol like http we need to track state (nonces just do not fit in well with single request http commands ;) ) so some database persistence will be needed. And if you already need to persist something I would really consider completely random code and store the code and the generation timestamp in database.

Your algorithm is really good if implemented correctly, for instance if you will display something like "Invalid iv for user 'Jane' or 123456" for tampered iv, then we do have an really big oops. Second thing is validation ;) I know that for you it's obvious but to often obvious things are the ones that get missed, so to validate the iv, and decipher the message, check validity of timestamp, and whether encrypted user id is matches the one in database for given iv. And there is a cryptographic  storage issues of course (the Insecure Cryptographic storage is among owasp's Top Ten after all). If you will be able to properly address those issues I think you will be good.

The final word, if your page wont be visited by billions of users, or not a target to some overly eager attacker You will do fine (you are encrypting only known values after all, userid and timestamp are not considered to be secret), and as to further reading section i recomend, Owasp's [Insecure cryptographic storage](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A7-Insecure_Cryptographic_Storage) and Ross Andersons **Security Engineering**, also the [Handbook Of applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) very educational :).

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. Very good point on resistant vs. evident. Tamper evident is what I am after and why I used GCM. I have the resources you mention except te insecure storage one - I will check that out. All error messages are along the lines of invalid request or expired request. User info only shows up if the reset code is verified.

Answer (score 0):

The two main issues I see:

- B64(iv || E(uid||timestamp)) is simpler and equivalent.
- uid||timestamp looks like it might be vulnerable to "cryptographic splicing" (except you say that you recover the UID from the token, which should be fine).
- If the IV is stored in the DB, it does not need to be in the token (and perhaps shouldn't be in the token).

Assuming uid/timestamp have no confidentiality requirements, the main advantage of using authenticated encryption is that you can't forget to check the MAC: D() just returns an error. There are still some language/implementation-dependent problems:

- In most C APIs, if you ignore the error you end up reading whatever was in the output buffer. (If the decryption is in-place, then the output buffer is attacker-controlled!)
- If a decryption error outputs the empty string and sets an error flag, you might end up with `int('') == 0` and `timestamp('') == timestamp()`.

The main advantage of storing an (unkeyed) hash is that you don't need to worry about key storage/compromise.